# How to disable Plutext in Docx4j.net?

Tags: c#, .net, docx, docx4j, tableofcontents

I'm trying to run TOC Update exmaple, but whenever I try to generate TOC with numbering I keep getting the following error:

```
[INFO]  org.docx4j.Docx4J - org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.FOExporterVisitor not found; 
if you want it, add docx4j-export-FO to your path. Doing so will disable Plutext's 
PDF Converter./norg.docx4j.convert.out.fo.FOExporterVisitor
[INFO]  org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils - Using NamespacePrefixMapper 
RelationshipsPartSunInternal, which is suitable for Java 6

Looks like you have the wrong host in your endpoint URL 'http://convertereval.plutext.com:80/v1/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/convert'
```

As I understand it would be just enough to disable Plutext's converter. The problem is that I can't manage to achieve that - tried adding docx4j-export-fo.jar to path but didn't help. Please instruct me how can I get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a docx4j-export-fo dll right now, so if you want ToC page numbers, your best bet might be to install the converter locally (get it from https://converter-eval.plutext.com/ ), then point to that using your properties file.